# Prevent "show" event to trigger of "tabs" widget on page load in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using tabs widget of jquery to display some content. It works ok but I need tabs to show first tab content but not trigger "show" event when page loads. Later it should trigger show event when I change tabs. Is this possible?

***Edit: Problem solved***

Ok I solved my problem but let me explain what I was trying to do.

My tabs were in a container and I was using .animate() to adjust css top value according to the height of my selected tab content to keep everything in the middle of the page. But on page load, I want to show content of first tab but not animate so the code below didn't work because it triggers show event when page loads.

```
$( ".tabs" ).tabs({
   show: function(event, ui) { animatemycontainer() }
});
```

But this code does what I need. It simply binds show event after tabs are created so it doesn't trigger show event on page load.

```
$( ".tabs" ).tabs();
$(".tabs").bind("tabsshow", function(event, ui) {
    animatemycontainer();
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about not showing any tab content on page load. You have to click on a tab to show?

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ selected: -1 });
```

I googled and found the documentation here: [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected)